# Retail Mac OS for MacbookPro 2,2?

Tags: macbook-pro, apple-store

What is best OS for  MacbookPro 2,2 with new Harddisk(empty),  3GB RAM and 500GB HDD ?

Mac OS 10.6 or 10.7 Retail will work ?

ps: I am not having the Restoration DVD's came with macbook.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Everymac](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-2-duo-2.16-15-specs.html) it can use anything from 10.4.8 to 10.7.5

I'd always be inclined to go for the latest OS a machine can use, even though it might make it slower than the earliest.

Comment: I am noob to Mac; When i try to install from my friend disk it is not booted/installed. Is it same with Retail Versions ?

Comment: Broadly - Versions that are supplied with new Macs are essentially for that model only. Retail versions will work on any model capable of running that OS.

Comment: you will most likely have to buy 10.6 as that is the last one you can get new on disk. You can update to 10.7 after you install 10.6 (Leaving aside any used install disk options)